# Differentiating size of Lego blocks in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, lego-mindstorms

I wanted to ask how I could count certain type of Lego block in am image in MATLAB. 
I am able to counts blocks of a certain color.

But I cannot seem to work out how to differentiate size and type of a certain block. I need to count the number of 4 by 2 blue blocks in a set of images.

[I need count how many of this block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSVsy.png)

[And this block are in the images below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iT1M.png)

This includes those that are upside down or at different orientations.
Examples of images are below.

[In this image there are 3 blue and 1 red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQrx6.png)

[In this image there is only 1 blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCMPf.png)

[Three blue and two red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hZzH.png)

Any help in MATLAB will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some example images?

Comment: I have added example images in the question.